# How to use MFA in Javascript aws-sdk?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have an infrastructure where AWS login happens on a Role basis requires MFA from MS authenticator which pops up on Mobile device for Accept or Decline. Normally on CLI, we use saml2aws and it generates temporary access key secret key with assume role.

I am trying to use aws-sdk in my nodejs and trying to validate the credentials but not getting any popup and gets below error.

Please suggest the method or way to achieve this.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var eks = new AWS.EKS({ accessKeyId: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", secretAccessKey : "gsdhjfkjbkbfvfkqbvfhvqhfvqhfv", region: "us-west-2"});
var params = { name: "testing" };
  
eks.describeCluster(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

After executing the above code: I am receiving the below error:

```
UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.
    at Object.extractError (D:\Prashant\kubernetes-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:52:27)
    at Request.extractError (D:\Prashant\kubernetes-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Prashant\kubernetes-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (D:\Prashant\kubernetes-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (D:\Prashant\kubernetes-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (D:\Prashant\kubernetes-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (D:\Prashant\kubernetes-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at D:\Prashant\kubernetes-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Prashant\kubernetes-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Prashant\kubernetes-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:690:12) {
  code: 'UnrecognizedClientException',
  time: 2020-11-03T22:36:19.516Z,
  requestId: '2e3486d0-3219-410c-8963-970958c5c14d',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 91.55836550904752
}
```

Comment: Please post the solution in your answer, not everyone can comment as @callback has said in the answer

Answer (score 3):

There's a variety of ways you can get your credentials, the AWS docs recommend the official npm package ["@aws-sdk/credentials-providers"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/credential-providers)

Of these, the ones I found most useful where:

- `fromEnv`: Gets the relevant credentials from environment variables.

  Also ideal for a CI script.
- `fromIni`: Which uses your `~/.aws/config` and credentials file.

Example:

```js
import { ListBucketsCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { fromIni, fromEnv } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers";
import * as readline from "readline";

function getCredentials(ci = process.env.CI) {
  if (ci) {
    return fromEnv();
  }

  // This assumes that you've set-up your ~/.aws/config and credentials!
  return fromIni({
    profile: "MY-PROFILE",
    mfaCodeProvider: async (serial) => await prompt(
        `Type the mfa token for the following account: ${serial}\n`
    ),
  });
}


const s3Client = new S3Client({
  credentials: getCredentials(),
});

const test = await s3Client.send(new ListBucketsCommand({}));

console.log("Response:", test);


// Helper function for node-js
function prompt(query) {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });

  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    rl.question(query, (ans) => {
      rl.close();
      resolve(ans);
    })
  );
}
```

By saving the previous snippet as 'test.mjs' we can now test our connection to AWS' various services (S3, being the simplest, is here as an example).

So we can now use a program like [awsume](https://awsu.me/general/quickstart.html) to assume a role; getting all of the relevant environment variables for us and see if a given role succeeds in getting our data, or we can just type the token provided to us by the MFA

Example:

```bash
$ node test.mjs
Type the mfa token for the following account: <some account>
<Token from your Authenticator App>
Response: <etc>
```

Or

```bash
$ source awsume MY-PROFILE
Enter MFA token: <MFA token>
[MY-PROFILE] Role credentials will expire # <Some date>
$ CI=true node test.mjs
Response: # <etc>
```

Edit: Some time later we had issues running this code from inside an EC2 instance. Turns out that in that context the credentials are all "baked-in" and there's no need to use the [credentials-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/credential-providers)

The original `getCredentials` can be adapted to:

```js
function getCredentials(ci = process.env.CI, in_ec2 = process.env.CI) {
  if (in_ec2) {
    return undefined;
  }

  if (ci) {
    return fromEnv();
  }

  // This assumes that you've set-up your ~/.aws/config and credentials!
  return fromIni({
    profile: "MY-PROFILE",
    mfaCodeProvider: async (serial) => await prompt(
        `Type the mfa token for the following account: ${serial}\n`
    ),
  });
}
```